# How to escape single quotes while printing in php twitter autotweet?

Tags: php, twitter, html-escape-characters

I have functionality to Autotweet text into twitter account. Everything is working fine, 
    but when text contains any single quotes , It post in to twitter as below..

Example:
   Actual text and expected result : Maneka's 'Beti Bachao' drive goes live

Text displayed in twitter       : Maneka�s �Beti Bachao� drive goes live

Please let me know how to escape these single quotes while in php.

Regards,
Kiran.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) like this:

```
<?php
$str = "A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>";

// Outputs: A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str);

// Outputs: A &#039;quote&#039; is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES);
?>
```